# Replace the %20 that means a space on iron router

Tags: javascript, node.js, iron-router, meteor

I'm trying to replace the %20 that means space on the url by another character,

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('promos', {
    path: '/:promo_name',
    waitOn: function(){
        return Meteor.subscribe("promo", this.params.promo_name);
    },
    data: function(){
      return Promociones.findOne({'metadata.nombrePromo': this.params.promo_name});
    }
  });
});
```

This is how I generate dynamic routes, and i get something like this *http://padonde.mx/Pi%C3%B1a%20Colada%202x1* i want to replace the %20 by another character like *-* or *+*, is this possible on iron router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually an stander URL encoding, and its set by the browser not
iron-router.

You can do this,

Where you insert the

```
'metadata.nombrePromo', add another field to the collection like
```

`'metadata.nombrePromoReplace'`, and do this.
i guess you have something like

var `nombrePromo = $('#idElementPromo').val();`, or a `session` or whatever you pass the value to the metadata

so based on that var `nombrePromo` do this.

```
var nombrePromoReplace = nombrePromo.replace(/\s+/g, '');
```

and now change the route.

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('promos', {
    path: '/:promo_name',
    waitOn: function(){
        return Meteor.subscribe("promo", this.params.promo_name);
    },
    data: function(){
      return Promociones.findOne({'metadata.nombrePromoReplace': this.params.promo_name});
    }
  });
});
```

Now when you navigate to /:promo_name, and if you added something like

```
i have blanks spaces
```

the route should be

```
/ihaveblankspaces
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any Iron-Router configuration that could change this, but here is what you can do:

Add the little package called Collection Helpers:

```
$ meteor add dburles:collection-helpers
```

Then define a virtual field in your Collection (for Example: polished_promo_name):

```
Promociones.helpers({
  polished_promo_name: function() {
    return this.promo_name.replace(/ /g, "AnotherCharacter");
  }
});
```

And now of course use polished_promo_name instead of promo_name and replace the spaces back in:

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('promos', {
    path: '/:polished_promo_name',
    waitOn: function(){
      return Meteor.subscribe("promo", this.params.polished_promo_name.replace(/AnotherCharacter/g, " "));
    },
    data: function(){
      return Promociones.findOne({'metadata.nombrePromo': this.params.polished_promo_name.replace(/AnotherCharacter/g, " ")});
    }
  });
});
```